# converting numbers to consonant-vowel pairs

Tags: python

the project specifically asks to divide the initial set of numbers into base 10, so like 6|30|45|10 by using the % 100 and // 100 operators, then converting the last 2 digits into a quotient between 0-19 and remainder between 0-4 by using % 5 and // 5. currently i have, any help appreciated, thanks!

```
integer = pin
number_string = str(integer)
number_string2 = str(integer)
number_string % 100
number_string2 // 100

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m",
          "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "y", "z"]
```

`
the code should produce this in end

```
>>> pintoword(3463470)
'bomejusa'
>>> pintoword(3464140)
'bomelela'
```

Comment: I honestly do not understand your question

Comment: basically starting from low order of the base 10's of a 4-digit or more number, i need to convert the digits into a letter so say that 40 % 5 gives me 0, it would assign the letter a, and 40 // 5 is 8 so it would give me the letter l.

Comment: It almost looks like you mean base 100. '40' is two digits in base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is a bit strange. For example, you convert a variable named `integer` to a string, and then you attempt to perform arithmetic on it. And then you don't save the result anywhere!

Anyway, here's some code that does what you want. It uses the built-in `divmod` function to generate the quotient and remainder in one function call.

```
vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"

def pintoword(n):
    a = []
    while n:
        n, r = divmod(n, 100)
        c, v = divmod(r, 5)
        a.append(vowels[v])
        a.append(consonants[c])
    return ''.join(reversed(a))

for n in (3463470, 3464140):
    print n, pintoword(n)
```

**output**

```
3463470 bomejusa
3464140 bomelela
```

We save the letter pairs in a list and join them together in a string at the end. The divide by 100 operation generates the letter pairs in reverse order, so we need to reverse the list before we join it.

---

FWIW, here's a function that performs the inverse operation. Rather than doing `.index` calls on the `vowels` and `consonants` strings it uses a pair of dictionaries to look up the indices, since that's faster.

```
def invert_string(s):
    return dict((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(s))

dvowels = invert_string(vowels)
dconsonants = invert_string(consonants)

def wordtopin(s):
    ''' Convert string s of alternating consonants and vowels into an integer '''
    num = 0
    for c, v in zip(*[iter(s)]*2):
        num = 100 * num + 5 * dconsonants[c] + dvowels[v]
    return num
```